# Set PATH env variable when running CMake projects with VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a C++ application (built with CMake) that dynamically loads `dxcompiler.dll` to compile HLSL shaders to SPIRV using the Vulkan SDK on Windows (my global `PATH` variable contains `C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.239.0\Bin` at the first position).

When running and compiling the application using Visual Studio Community 2022 it runs correctly: it loads the dll included in the Vulkan SDK. Same behavior when manually running the `.exe` from explorer or from the terminal.

But when I run the application from VSCode (with or without debugging) it automatically loads the `dll` included in the Windows SDK (that incidentally doesn't allow SPIRV compilation).

I discovered that VSCode changes my PATH variable prepending various Windows SDK/VS-related paths:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX64\x64;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;
.......a lot more paths.......
```

I don't know if the culprit is VSCode, the C++ extension or the CMake extension, I didn't find docs specifically for this problem. Is it possible to disable this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you start VS Code from [a VS Developer Command Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell)? If so, that could be the reason.

Comment: @user no, I even tried `echo %PATH%` from the terminal inside VSCode and it's clean, it doesn't contain any windows sdk path